# I want SetEditing set to YES all the time so the user can ALWAYS reorder rows. However, I don't want to Ins/Del indent space

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a Scene that allows the user to reorder rows. I call [self.tableView setEditing:YES] in viewDidLoad.

Here's what else I have...

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL canEdit = NO;

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
        canEdit = NO;
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
        canEdit = YES;

    return canEdit;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCellEditingStyle style = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

    if (indexPath.section == 0)
        style = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
        style = UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;

    return style;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 1)
        return YES;

    return NO;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    FFFPlayer *data = [self.myData objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.myData removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [self.myData data atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
}
```

I only want the user to be able to reorder rows in section 1.

I'm having 2 issues.

1) the Reorder control is on the row the entire time, and it can be reordered... but all the UILabel data on the row is being indented to make room for a non-existent Delete/Insert button. Despite using UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone, everything remains indented. How can I solve/work-around this? I want rows to remain reorderable at all times, but no indent.

2) Right now I am able to take a row from section 1 and reorder and move it into section 0. How do I prevent this. I only want rows from section 1 to move around it's own section.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For issue 1 you do:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}
```

Your `editingStyle...` method can simply be:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

And you `canEdit...` method can simply be:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return indexPath.section == 1;
}
```

For issue 2 you need to implement the following:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section == sourceIndexPath.section) {
        return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
    } else {
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
    }
}
```

That code assumes you can only move rows in section 1 and there are only 2 sections.